# Custom tooltip control in WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip

Is there a simple way to create and show a custom tooltip control in C# / WinForms?

My current thinking is either:

- create a subclass of Tooltip,
  override the OnPaint method, set it
  as the parent control's tooltip
- create a subclass of form and show
  it manually

Any thoughts?

Comment: Go ahead! What's the problem?

Comment: Just wondered if anyone had a better method.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on what you need for your tool tip. If you only need a tool tip with balloon shape, animation and fading effects with custom text color and background, It is easier to use ToolTip control

```
 // Create your control
 System.Windows.Forms.Button trialButton = new Button();
 trialButton.Text = "Trial Button";

 // Tool tip string
 string toolTipText = "Hello World";
 // ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip(this.components);
 ToolTip toolTip = new ToolTip();
 toolTip.ToolTipTitle = "ToolTip Title";
 toolTip.UseAnimation = true;
 toolTip.UseFading = true;
 toolTip.IsBalloon = true;
 toolTip.Active = true;
 toolTip.SetToolTip(button, toolTipText);
```