# Rich Text in ToolTip for C#

Tags: c#, winforms, tooltip, richtextbox

I can extend the ToolTip and create my own RichToolTip but I don't understand how I can handle formatting per line or Per word. Can I add controls which a user can click on ? or images etc.

I came across [RichTextBox](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/RichToolTipCtrl.aspx) but this is written in C++ (MFC) & I want something for C# or something which I can use with C#. Any suggestions? Are there any open source components which I can use?

```
 public class RichToolTip : ToolTip
    {
    public RichToolTip()
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(OnDraw);
    }

    public RichToolTip(System.ComponentModel.IContainer Cont)
    {
        this.OwnerDraw = true;
        this.Draw += new DrawToolTipEventHandler(OnDraw);
    }
    private void OnDraw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
    {
        DrawToolTipEventArgs newArgs = new DrawToolTipEventArgs(e.Graphics,
                        e.AssociatedWindow, e.AssociatedControl, e.Bounds, e.ToolTipText.Substring(0, 5),
                        this.BackColor, this.ForeColor, new Font("Arial Unicode MS", 8.25f, FontStyle.Bold));
        newArgs.DrawBackground();
        newArgs.DrawBorder();
        newArgs.DrawText(TextFormatFlags.TextBoxControl);
    }
}
```

Comment: you may find your answer here: [Custom tooltip control in WinForms](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818335/custom-tooltip-control-in-winforms)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [this HTML renderer](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/GDI-plus/HtmlRenderer.aspx).

Comment: Awesome !! I still have to check if it has decent performance.

Comment: Note, There are few bugs here and there. </br> or <br></br> does not work .. HtmlToolTip instance format itself based upon last time being displayed in the tooltip. It does not support display of html content.

Comment: @Kare: Those are invalid HTML.  It supports most HTML tags.

Answer (score 0):

This is the newer version of HTML renderer @SLaks - https://htmlrenderer.codeplex.com