# In C#, in tooltip how to change different color for differnt part of text?

Tags: c#, tooltip

In the MS chart, I am displaying tooltip using below code.

```
ToolTip ToolTip = new ToolTip();
ToolTip .Show(" X value:"+s+"\nLine 1 Y value: =" + ss + "\nLine 2 Y value:=" + ss1, chart, (int)e.Location.X, (int)e.Location.Y);
```

I am able to set only one foreground color using ToolTip .ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;.

I am new to C#.

How to assign a different colour and draw text in custom tooltip class or how to use HTML renderer to achieve my requirement?

I could not assign a different colour for a different part of the tooltip text.

How to achieve it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rich Text in ToolTip for C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459452/rich-text-in-tooltip-for-c-sharp)

Comment: @Orel, the answer you suggested didn't tell how to assign different colors in custom tooltip class. I am new to C#. What is htmlrender and how to use it in tooltip?

Comment: You can owner-draw the tooltip.

Answer (score 1):

You can owner-draw the tooltip

[image]

Example:

```
ToolTip ToolTip = new ToolTip();
ToolTip.OwnerDraw = true;
ToolTip.Popup += (ss, ee) => { ee.ToolTipSize = new Size(200, 50);  };

ToolTip.Draw += (ss, ee) =>
{
    ee.DrawBackground();
    ee.DrawBorder();
    ee.Graphics.DrawString("Warning", Font, Brushes.Red, 10, 1);
    ee.Graphics.DrawString(ee.ToolTipText, Font, Brushes.Black, 1, 22);

};

ToolTip.Show("Demo only", somecontrol..);
```

This is just a simple example; there are many more parameters to style the tooltip, including drawing stuff, images, brushes of all types, etc..

It is also recommended to use `TextRenderer` instead of the classic GDI+ `DrawString`.

Note how I set the `Size` in the `PopUp` event!

All sorts of formatting is possible with the text; for multiline text it is recommended to use an overload with bounding rectangle instead of x/y coordinates and maybe also alignment with a `StringFormat`. Do note though, that is is always tricky to embed formatted parts inside of a text.

Possible, but tedious to get really right, as always with GDI drawing. - 
The basic trick is to determine a bounding rectangle first; this can be done with `MeasureString`.

Comment: @Taw, I have multiple line text I don't want to hard code x,y position for drawstring. How to programmatically place the string at correct position.

Comment: Use the right [overload](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawstring?view=netframework-4.8#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawString_System_String_System_Drawing_Font_System_Drawing_Brush_System_Drawing_RectangleF_System_Drawing_StringFormat_) for Drawstring!

Answer (score 0):

The short answer would be "natively you simply can't" (Except you count drawing the label yourself as natively). But as always in programming there are creative ways to get the result you want.

The answer in the [Question Orel suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459452/rich-text-in-tooltip-for-c-sharp?noredirect=1&lq=1) basically makes use of a renderer for HTML Markup to render the styled text inside your application. 
If you have a look at the newer version of this library [here](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=htmlrenderer) they actually provide a WinForms ToolTip Control which accepts HTML Markup to render inside it's content area.

To use this renderer they provide a nuget package which makes installation trivial. Simply manage your projects nuget packages and search for HtmlRenderer.WinForms and install the latest version. (Check if it also installs the latest Version of HtmlRenderer.Core because it didn't on my end and I had to update the Core package)

After this rebuild your project to get the new controls in your designer toolbox.
To test the package I dragged a textbox and a HtmlToolTip onto my Form. To set the new toolTip you use it just like a normal WinForms tooltip.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
      InitializeComponent();

      this.htmlToolTip1.SetToolTip(this.textBox1, "<h1 style=\"color:red\">Hello</h1><i style=\"color:blue\">World</i>");
    }
}
```

Now you can style your toolTip content with HTML markup and change the foreground colors as you like:

[image: Screenshot]