# Can I pop up a help "speech bubble" over my Windows Form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a Windows Form with various controls on it, all positioned using `TableLayoutPanel` and the like.

When the user first uses my form, I'd like to pop up a speech-bubble type thing with information on how to use the form. I say speech-bubble because I want the "tail" to point at the part of the form I'm explaining. This would appear over part of the form (obscuring some controls).

Ideally, I'd like this speech-bubble to be oval/rounded, with transparent corners so that it looks more visually appealing, rather than being purely rectangular.

The popup should disappear after a short interval, or immediately if the user interacts with the controls on the form.

How can I do that?

Comment: The out of the box [ToolTip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4818335/custom-tooltip-control-in-winforms) control has quite a few knobs which might do the job?

Comment: StuartLC is right, you should be able to do that with tooltips

Comment: @StuartLC: Doesn't that mean that the user would need to hover over something to make the tooltip appear? I'd like the tip to appear as soon as the form is shown. I'd also like better control over how long it remained, etc. I've seen other posts complaining about the limitations of the ToolTip control, so I suspect it's not going to be a good starting point for me.

Comment: It looks like you can [programmatically control](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/63439/programatically-show-tooltip-in-winforms-application) when to show tooltip or not

Comment: I tried that method for showing the tooltip (in the Form_Shown event), but it didn't seem to work. However, the same question that you linked to also had another answer that shows how to create "balloon tips", which sounds like *exactly* what I'm after. So thanks for that! http://stackoverflow.com/a/12094327/98422

Comment: Aaaannd... all the way around the block and I'm back to tooltip, since it seems tooltips now support the "balloon" style! http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-create-a-balloon-tooltip-in-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/ I'm using this in conjunction with the `.Show()` method, which I've now got working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to supply an answer so that the question doesn't remain "unanswered", the tooltip control  now has an `IsBalloon` property that makes it appear in the desired style.

See [this link](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/how-to-create-a-balloon-tooltip-in-C-Sharp-and-windows-forms/) for a summary.